# Get file double click system arguments into application

Tags: linux

I created an C++ image processor for LINUX that opens a file browser when double clicked. When I run it from the commandline with a filename argument, it opens the file. I configured my system so that files with image extensions will use my program to open. Unfortunately, instead of opening the file as when launched with the filename on the commandline, my program acts as if there is no filename parameter being passed to the program and opens the file browser.

My question is; How do I get the filename argument from the O/S into my program when an image file that uses my program for opening is double clicked? I can't find this information anywhere. I'm assuming the filename is in argv[1], but obviously it is not. The program does not require a terminal to run.

I'm running Gnome Desktop on CENTOS/Linux 7, all current. Set up a Desktop icon that works fine to launch the application by clicking the icon. Problem is when double-clicking an image file, its name is not getting to the application, so the browser comes up. This is mysterious, because all commandline arguments work fine when running from a terminal. The big question is 'Where is the system putting the filename of the file that was double-clicked on?'

Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure the system to open your program?

Comment: You should add your desktop environment to make answers more precise. Some DEs may do this differently.

Answer (score 0):

You goofed up the .desktop file. [The `Exec` key needs one of `%f`, `%F`, `%u`, or `%U` so it knows what to process.](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html)

Comment: You may be right. That makes sense. I'll look into it. thanks.

Comment: In the desktop file I added the %f specifier to the Exec= keyword following the name of the executable as per spec. Sadly, no change in behavior. Application is still not finding arguments in argv[ ]... Valuable input; the %f was missing and it is required by the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The application can accept scripted image load and composition commands via a command file, or via streaming from another process. To accomplish this, the application was polling STDIN via the poll() system call at the top of the decision tree prior to processing arguments. It assumed that if STDIN is not empty, it contains a stream of commands to the application. This resulted in the O/S creating a new shell process to host the application. By moving the poll() system call to the end of the argument processing decision tree, the software behaves as expected. Not sure if the poll() system call is the best way to test if STDIN is empty, but it seems to work for that purpose.
Verdict:
Programming design error. My apologies for submitting such a murky problem.